# StaticLayout OutOfMemoryError with large text

Tags: android, out-of-memory, large-text, staticlayout

I get error when I use StaticLayout for create pagination of large text (~6mb).
This is my log:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:193)
at android.text.MeasuredText.addStyleRun(MeasuredText.java:269)
at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:291)
at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:143)
at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:93)
at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:71)
at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:51)
at com.ex.test.pagenation.Pagination.layout(Pagination.java:38)
at com.ex.test.pagenation.Pagination.<init>(Pagination.java:34)
at com.ex.test.pagenation.MainActivity$1.onGlobalLayout(MainActivity.java:51)
at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnGlobalLayout(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2006)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1200)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6401)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:573)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there any suggestion for fix this error? Or Is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite or extend Pagination class.
You should not put all the text into StaticLayout at once.
Instead, you should split text into parts. Parts should not be too lage.
I guess 10k-100k will be ok.
take first part, split it into pages, count pages, multiply it by amount of parts - that will be approximate quantity of pages in you book.
When a user want to see the past page of a first part, you should start second part just where the last page of first part begins. And so on.
Do not load all the text into StaticLayout - it is too much.

Comment: Sorry i use substring for split text into parts but i very slow with ~6mb text. Have you any solution suggest for me?